# Can you explain a sentence for me?

Tags: phrases

> The moment the bishop had finished his benediction, she squeezed quickly out of her row and darted out the cathedral's side entrance.

Can anybody explain the second part of this sentence in a brief and easy-to-understand way for me?

Comment: What is it you do not understand?

Comment: the whole second part sentence though i look up the meaning of the verb , i still dont know what it means

Comment: Which verb? **please specify that in your question**

Answer (score 4):

> she squeezed quickly out of her row

She is sitting in a pew in church, which is a long bench. There are people on both sides of her on the pew. She stands up and has very little space to move past them to the aisle. She moves through quickly.

> and darted out

A dart is a small spear or object that you throw or shoot at something. It moves very fast. The meaning here is that she moved quickly to the exit.

> the cathedral's side entrance.

A cathedral has several doors. There is one main door that is usually at the opposite end of the building from the altar. This is the door most people use to exit and enter the church. There are usually two side doors, as well. These are to the left and right of the altar. One of these side doors is the one she used to exit the church.